# jquery accordion is not working uploaded with wordpress self hosted technology

Tags: jquery, wordpress, accordion

I'm still a newbie here, and would like to ask you for a helping hand. I programmed a microsite based on html and css with some js and jquery pluggings. My first time with query and js.

The microsite is part of website hosted in dinahosting with  wordpress self-hosted technology. And when my client loads the microsite I made. It works completely but a jquery accordion in one of the sections, it does not open.

this is the website section live:

http://www.musicacreativa.com/wp-content/uploads/discos/caleidoscopio/temas.html

when you enter in "temas" section you have a list of songs ("Himno a la alegría" "Spunky",...). On click, the accordion should show more information.

I don't know why, I don't know pretty much about servers... I don't have enough reputation to upload screenshots, but the error console gives me lots of 500 internal server errors.

any ideas?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check that all files that are being requested are actually uploaded to the folder they are being requested from? I would double check each one with FTP access to make sure things are there

Comment: Before messing with the server and passwords of my client, I'm trying to upload the site somewhere else just to see if it works. Theoretically the only thing my client did was copy-paste all the files in a -zip I made. And I'm pretty sure they should be ok.

Comment: Not always, well worth checking first

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access the accordion script here: http://www.musicacreativa.com/wp-content/uploads/discos/caleidoscopio/js/jquery.accordion.js

When in actuality it's located here: http://www.musicacreativa.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/ui/jquery.ui.accordion.min.js

This is why your accordion isn't working.